# Filter maps inside list

Tags: groovy

I'm learning Groovy and I want to filter JSON (list of maps):

```
[
   {
      "username":"unnamed",
      "status":"offline",
      "last_activity":"2021-01-01",
   },
   {
      "username":"pachimasu",
      "status":"active",
      "last_activity":"2021-03-11",
   },
   {
      "username":"user",
      "status":"active",
      "last_activity":"2021-03-11",
   }
]
```

I want to filter `active` accounts. Expected output:

```
[
   {
      "username":"pachimasu",
      "status":"active",
      "last_activity":"2021-03-11",
   },
   {
      "username":"user",
      "status":"active",
      "last_activity":"2021-03-11",
   }
]
```

I ran:

```
def j = new JsonSlurper().parseText(text)

def expected = j.findAll {
    it.value.status == 'active'
}
```

But it throws exception: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'status' on null object`. As far I understand, `findAll` looping through elements inside lists, but not maps content inside this list. So, how can i loop through maps inside list and filter list by map values?

**UPDATE**

Source:

```
[
   {
      "username":"unnamed",
      "status":"offline",
      "last_activity":"2021-01-01",
      "subscribers": 100,
      "subscriptions": 3
   },
   {
      "username":"pachimasu",
      "status":"active",
      "last_activity":"2021-03-11",
      "subscribers": 1,
      "subscriptions": 28

   },
   {
      "username":"user",
      "status":"active",
      "last_activity":"2021-03-11"
   }
]
```

I want to get keys that have Integer values:

```
[
   {
      "subscribers": 100,
      "subscriptions": 3
   },
   {
      "subscribers": 1,
      "subscriptions": 28
   }
]
```

Comment: It's just `it.status`.  You must likely picked that up from an example filtering maps.

Comment: What if I want to filter this by only `value` without key mapping? For example I dont know json property name (status here). I want to loop through all maps values in list and find `active`, without using key names. This should return JSON with only `status` fields. It's kinda weird filtering, but still.

Comment: Or maybe i want to find only number values in maps. If `value` is a String (instanceof String?) i should skip it, and leave `key-values` only if it's number (Integer, Double, Number, etc).

Comment: There is no `it.value` here (or at least it's not in your JSON example). `it.value` (and `it.key`) are usually used when iterating **maps** - but you are filtering over a **list**.  Therefor `it` in your `findAll` will be a map from your list - so you need `it.status`.  And this way of filtering is not weird - this is how it is done in all major programming languages.

Comment: If you want to filter different things or filter dynamic things, then why don't you ask that question? If you oversimplify your question you will not get a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

Down below is a simple example of filtering by a known key-value, as well as by value only:

```
def j = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText '''
[
   {
      "username":"unnamed",
      "status":"offline",
      "last_activity":"2021-01-01",
   },
   {
      "username":"pachimasu",
      "status":"active",
      "last_activity":"2021-03-11",
   },
   {
      "username":"user",
      "status":"active",
      "last_activity":"2021-03-11",
   }
]'''

def expectedByKey = j.findAll{ it.status == 'active' }

assert expectedByKey.size() == 2

def expectedByValue = j.findAll{ it.any{ _, value -> value == 'offline' } }

assert expectedByValue.size() == 1
```

UPDATE:

By Integers can be filtered like so:

```
import groovy.json.*

def j = new JsonSlurper().parseText '''
[
   {
      "username":"unnamed",
      "status":"offline",
      "last_activity":"2021-01-01",
      "subscribers": 100,
      "subscriptions": 3
   },
   {
      "username":"pachimasu",
      "status":"active",
      "last_activity":"2021-03-11",
      "subscribers": 1,
      "subscriptions": 28

   },
   {
      "username":"user",
      "status":"active",
      "last_activity":"2021-03-11"
   }
]'''

def expectedByInts = j.findResults{ it.findAll{ _, v -> v in Integer } ?: null }

JsonOutput.prettyPrint JsonOutput.toJson( expectedByInts )
```

prints

```
[
    {
        "subscribers": 100,
        "subscriptions": 3
    },
    {
        "subscribers": 1,
        "subscriptions": 28
    }
]
```

Comment: I got it now. But what if i want to leave only that `key-values` (not all map) in each map if `value` match some criteria. I updated quesion with example.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `findResults` and `subMap` like so:

```
def data = [["username":"unnamed",
             "status":"offline",
             "last_activity":"2021-01-01",
             "subscribers": 100,
             "subscriptions": 3],
            ["username":"pachimasu",
             "status":"active",
             "last_activity":"2021-03-11",
             "subscribers": 1,
             "subscriptions": 28],
            ["username":"user",
             "status":"active",
             "last_activity":"2021-03-11"]]

println data.findResults{
    it.containsKey('subscriptions') ? it.subMap('subscriptions','subscribers') : null
}
// → [[subscriptions:3, subscribers:100], [subscriptions:28, subscribers:1]]
```

Note, that you need some condition to mark an item as valid.  Here the
existence of a `subscriptions` key is used.